# Splay Tree insertion time efficiency with different input cases

Tags: c++, data-structures, insertion, splay-tree

So I used the same splaytree used in geeksforgeeks and did some experiment with it:

code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-in-splay-tree/?ref=rp

vers.1

```cpp
    #include <ctime>
    // the code for splaytree is too long so I just put the link here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-in-splay-tree/?ref=rp
    double t1=clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        x = rand()%max_x;
        root = insert(root, x);
    }

    double t2=clock();
    double result = (t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("insertion time: %f\n", result);
```

vers.2

```cpp
    int x;
    double t1=clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        x = rand()%max_x;
        root = insert(root, i);
    }

    double t2=clock();
    double result = (t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("insertion time: %f\n", result);
```

## OUTPUT:

for vers. 1: the insertion time is
`cpp insertion time: 0.779000`
for vers. 2: the insertion time is
`insertion time: 0.156000`

I know Splay tree "splays" every time it does insertion, so consider that `rand` may generates same outputs sometimes, why splay tree works much faster when it takes 1000000 distinct inputs? That doesn't make any sense to me. (I am a student and yea my English is bad sorry about it).

## EDIT:

I modified vers.2 to:

```cpp
    int x;
    double t1 = clock();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        x = rand()%max_x;
        printf("%d",x);
        root = insert(root, i);
    }

    double t2=clock();
    double result = (t2-t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("insertion time: %f\n", result);
```

modified vers.2 output:

```
 ....a bunch of numbers...time: 0.569000
```

still faster than vers. 1

Comment: In first case you are inserting random values, in the second only ones. That is not the same benchmark?

Comment: sorry that is a typo, it is `i` but the result is similiar, it is still much faster than the first case

Comment: Calling `rand()`  slows it down. You are comparing optimized builds I assume?

Comment: I modified it to```cpp
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        x = rand()%max_x;
        root = insert(root, i);
    }```
still much faster than the first case

Comment: Since you are not using `x` the compiler will most probably just throw that call to `rand` away from vers.2.

Comment: it makes sense, lemme modify it again

Comment: You are building a different tree, of course it will take different amount time? Insertion depth is crucial for running time.

Comment: may you elaborate a lit bit more please? I think the depth of splaytree in vers.2 is deeper than that of vers.1 ? But why'd it be faster. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: When you insert items in order, you build a perfectly left-skewed tree, so inserts always find the nearest element at the root. You are basically pushing onto a linked list. That's about as cheap as insert can be.  If you want to see this, try the animation at https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/SplayTree.html  If you look up some random elements between inserts, the tree will become more balanced so inserts will slow down.

Comment: thank you so much I get it now!!! How do I mark this as answered lol Im new to stackoverflow